# Casting a RedisValue to a generic type

Tags: c#, redis, casting

I am trying to convert `RedisValue` to a generic Type T but i am getting a casting error while trying to cast string 'False' / 'True' to boolean

```
public T? Get<T>(string key)
    {
        T? result = default;
        var redisValue = _database.StringGet(key);
        if (redisValue.HasValue)
        { 
            result = (T?) Convert.ChangeType(redisValue, typeof(T));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Error

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast from Raw to long: 'False'
> at StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue.op_Explicit(RedisValue value) in /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisValue.cs:line 615
> at StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue.op_Explicit(RedisValue value) in /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisValue.cs:line 584
> at StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider
> provider) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisValue.cs:line 893
> at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
> at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)

I am adding values to redis cache as follows:

```
public bool AddOrUpdate<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            return value != null && _database.StringSet(key, value.ToString());
        }
```